# Añadir EventListener a una lista de elementos [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando con JavaScript y la programación en general y necesito mostrar el id de un div sobre el que tengo situado el ratón, formando dicho div parte de una lista de divs pertenecientes a un div padre "principal". Para ello, hago lo siguiente:

```
var principal = document.getElementById('principal');
var lista = principal.children;
```

Suponiendo que tenga la lista bien creada... ¿Cómo agrego un evento que me muestre el id del div sobre el que tengo situado el ratón? Sé que es con el evento "mouseover" pero he hecho varias pruebas y no acaba de funcionar como yo quiero.

Espero haberme explicado con claridad ¡Gracias de antemano y un saludo!

Comment: Sin ver el **HTML** es complicado saber si el problema lo tienes ahí. Podría ser que no estés usando un selector correcto para el elemento **HTML** al que deseas asociar la función **onmouseover**. Sin ver también el **JS** con el que estás tratando de mostrar la **ID** no sabemos si el problema está en la manera que tratas de hacerlo. Y sin saber a que te refieres con "no acaba de funcionar como yo quiero" no sabemos el problema que estás teniendo.

Comment: Cuéntanos un poco más acerca de esas pruebas que has hecho. Pon algo de código de lo que has probado, algo con lo que podamos reproducir lo que quieres hacer exactamente, los problemas que has tenido (errores o similar)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
//seleccionamos el id principal y obtenemos sus hijos!
var principal = document.getElementById("principal").children;

// interamos por cada hijo 
for(let i=0; i < principal.length;i++){
  // le asiganos un evento mouseover
  principal[i].addEventListener("mouseover",(e)=>{
  // obtenemos el target o seleccion y obtenemos su id
  // y lo colocamos como texto en span sele
  document.getElementById("sele").innerText = e.target.id;
});
}
```

```html
<div>seleccion: <span id="sele" style="color:green;font-weight: bold;"> </span></div> 
<div id="principal" style="cursor:pointer">
  <div id="ids1">1</div>
  <div id="ids2">2</div>
  <div id="ids3">3</div>
  <div id="ids4">4</div>
  <div id="ids5">5</div>
  <div id="ids6">6</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: mil gracias! en cuanto llegue a casa lo pruebo :D